# How to remove a certain role after 24 hours?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello I have recently begun a little discord.py project, just writing code for bots and learning python alongside it :D

My goal is this: to have the bot remove a role from a user after having that role for 24 hours. I already figured out how to assign them the roles using the bot, I'm just clueless as to how to make the bot take it away from them after 24 hours.

Thank you for all the help!

-Gary

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to this and I don't believe in spoonfeeding I'll point you to what *might* work for you. Take what you may
[Tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/), a [db](https://pypi.org/project/redis/0) and [datetime](https://pypi.org/project/DateTime/).